# SQS Queue not deleting all messages

Tags: python, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to get all the messages from my sqs queue, I'm deleting each message from the queue after I'm reading it, In some point I still have messages in the queue but I'm stop getting them and got message that the queue is empty.

```
    while sqs_message:
    message_id = sqs_message[0].message_id
    **some logic here**
    sqs_message.delete()
    sqs_message = queue.receive_messages(MaxNumberOfMessages=10)
```

Comment: Is this your actual code? If not, can you please use it instead? How are you looping through the list of messages returned from `receive_messages()`? One part appears to be accessing `sqs_message[0]`, but not any of the other entries in the list. Also, `sqs_message.delete()` won't work because it is a list, not a message.

Comment: check this out: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteMessage.html